# Removing text from title in an array using Vue

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am trying to replace the text "this | " with "" from the titles in an array.

What is the best way to do this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

my js code:

```
let Feed=require('rss-to-json')
Feed.load('http://localhost:3000/news', function (err, content) {
  let appTitleList = new Vue({
    el: '#news',
    data: {
      rssItems: content.items
    },
    methods:{
      removeFunction: function () {
       this.content.title = this.content.title.replace("this | ", "");
    }
  })
})
```

the html:

```
         <div class="card" id="news">
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in rssItems" > 
                    <b>{{ item.title }}</b>
                    <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: "_titles in an array_" which array are you referring to here? could you please add a few sample data about how that array looks like? Also, do you want to replace it from all objects title property inside the array?

Comment: that is one item in the array, apologies for the unkind formatting

Comment: This doesn't seem like an array but more like an XML. Also, inside title there no `this | ` but you have `News24.com | ` instead?

Comment: yes it is xml - I have edited original question to reflect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see what `this.content` is. I don't see where you are using `removeFunction`, but if you are, try this:

```
removeFunction: function () {
    const rssItems = [...this.rssItems]
    for (const item of rssItems) {
        item.title = item.title.replace("this | ", "");
    }
    this.rssItems = rssItems
}
```

Alternatively, mutate the `rssItems` before setting them in the state, and maybe you won't need the `removeFunction`.

```
data: {
  rssItems: content.items.map(i => ({
    ...i,
    title: i.title.replace("this | ", "")
  }))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, your alternative method worked!

I had to edit it slightly and use the following,

    data: {
      rssItems: content.items.map(i => ({
        ...i,
        title: i.title.replace("News24.com | ", ""),
      })
    )}

Comment: quick question,

If there were multiple things to replace in the title, what would be the best approach using your alternative?

Comment: Add another `replace`: `title: i.title.replace("News24.com | ", "").replace("Other Thing", "")`.

Comment: You are a Super Star!

Have a great weekend all!

Comment: @cgd You can vote or accept an answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

This can be a possible solution: fetching your API's posts when the Vue.JS instance is created, mutating the related titles and enqueue each post.

```
<head>
... your imports from CDN
</head>

<body>
   <div id="app">
      <div class="card" id="news">
         <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
            <li class="list-group-item" v-for="item in items"> 
               <b>{{ item.title }}</b>
               <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>

   <script>
   new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
         return {
            items: []
         }
      },
      created () {
         Feed.load('your-api-endpoint', (err, content) => {
            // TODO: error handling...

            for (let i = 0; i < content.items.length; i++) {
               const item = content.items[i];

               // Mutate the title and enqueue the post
               item.title = item.title.replace('Title | ', '');
               this.items.push(item);
            }
         });
      }
   })
   </script>
</body>
```

Also, watch out that the field `data` in the Vue.JS instance must be a function, not an object. More about this, [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#data-Must-Be-a-Function).

Comment: thank you Federico, I couldn't get yours to work with my code, but I thank you nevertheless :)

Comment: Happy to be helpful.